# Drawing on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a putpixel functionality in html5. I have a canvas and want to draw on the canvas using mouse. How should I wright the javascript function for that. How can can I take the coordinate value on mouseclick and change the pixel value as soon as the user clicks.

Comment: This question should have gone to Google.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher :ok sir. But unfortunately I cannot delete it now as there are answers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation/  section "Putting this into practice" using jquery:

```
$(canvas).click(function(e) {  
    var canvasOffset = $(canvas).offset();  
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);  
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);  

    // do here whatever you want
});
```

Read the article for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a intermediate knowledge of Javascript try reading a tutorial like this:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/